# How do we express we visit or talk to a friend who is sick to know whether he is alright?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Your friend is sick.

In some countries, it is a good practice to either visit or talk to him/his wife/his parents  to know whether he is alright.

**Is that practice common in English speaking countries?**

**How do we express it?**

Because I often hear people say "**Thanks for asking!**", I guess we say "**I asked him about his health**"

Comment: Yes, of course it is! If we can't visit the invalid in person we speak to  their relative/close friend to **ask after** them.

Comment: *Caveat:* Nowadays, there may be *privacy* issues with getting too much information on someone's health. In the U.S., *HIPAA* may restrict access. That said, this has nothing to do with English usage, nor with a polite concern about a friend; it's merely a legal complication... sigh